# Why does 'git status' ignore the .gitattributes clean filter?

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have a [.gitattributes clean filter](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion) to remove all comments from a file before committing.

```
$ cat .git/config
[filter "cleancomments"]
    clean = "grep -v '^#'"

$ cat .gitattributes
*   filter=cleancomments
```

And I have a file 'test' with following content (committed in the repository):

```
This is a file with random content
```

Now I make a modification to 'test' and add comments:

```
This is a file with random content
# and some comments
# like this
```

`git status` now tells me:

```
modified:   test
```

but `git diff` is empty (as it should).

It is not completely clear to me **why git status does not use the filter to decide if a file has been modified or not**, but I assume this is how it is implemented.

What is really mysterious to me is following:

If I do this:

```
git add test
```

Then suddenly the file 'test' is no longer marked as modified and it does not appear in the git index. Why is this?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to remove all the comments from a file? Just curious, you obviously have your reasons, but there's few scenarios where it's actually a sane thing to do.

Comment: This is just a very simplified example of what I really do :-) I have tested my example and it works as described. The real scenario involves removing comments from .po files because they are hardly ever useful, can always be automatically re-generated and cause many conflicts when several developers edit the same file.

Answer (score 8):

`git add` adds the file to the index,<sup>1</sup> but runs it through any required filters first.

The index contains the file's on-disk name and "true name" (its git hash as a "blob") along with directory `stat` values and a pair of git hash values (original and filtered), plus some other bits and bobs as needed.  Once `add`-ed, `git status` can tell from the index data that the file is now "up to date" in the index, and the index itself is up to date in the repository as the blob's hash matches the `HEAD` commit hash.

If you modify the file some more, though, some key `stat` data changes, making git think the index is out of date, and `git status` will once again think it needs to be `git add`-ed.<sup>2</sup>

The general idea here seems to be that `git status` does not write anything (even the index).  It might be nice if `git update-index --refresh` would update the work-dir/cleaned-entry pairing, but it does not seem to.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, `git add` computes the hash—and hence the "true name" in the repo—and then adds the object to the repo if and only if it's not already present.  The hash value is now known and can be stored in the index as needed.  The hash value is unknown until after doing the filtering and hashing, i.e., `git status` doesn't know it.

<sup>2</sup>There are more subtleties here if you use things like `--assume-unchanged` and/or `core.ignorestat`.

Comment: Is there any way to make 'git status' take more time and take into account the filter/clean? Or is there any other way to avoid the file being marked as 'modified' without having to 'git add' it?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be.  However, `git add -u .` will add everything needed to clear out the "modified" status-es (if they're "really changed" it also adds them of course).  Incidentally, I tested this and just modifying the date doesn't cause it to show up again, i.e., I was wrong about simply using `touch test`, so now I'm much less sure what stat information `git status` is checking.  (I did a brief scan through the code some time ago, I know it uses lstat() heavily...)