# How to handle keyword expansion in parallel GIT + CVS project

Tags: git, version-control, cvs

I have a project I track in both CVS and GIT.
CVS ignores the .git folder, GIT ignores all the CVS sub-folders.
The GIT repo was created with `git cvsimport`, so they both have the same history.

Works pretty well, except:

Some files have CVS-style keywords which on a `cvs update` get expanded.
GIT then shows them as changes.

If I delete the keyword expansion (cvsimport was done with `-k`, so they are non-expanded in the GIT repo), they no longer show changes to git, but instead show up as changes when comparing to CVS.

Is there a way to keep them expanded in CVS, but non-expanded in GIT without them showing up as changed?

**My partial solution:**

I used .gitattributes and .git/config to set a custom filter

.gitattributes

```
*.txt filter=ignId
```

.git/config

```
[filter "ignId"]
    clean = ./ignId.sh %f
    smudge = cat
```

ignId.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sed  -e "s@\\\$Id:[^\\\$]*@\\\$Id@g" $1
```

and it works on `git diff` and probably also on `git commit`(haven't tried that one yet), but `git status` still shows the files as changed.

How do I make `git status` ignore the changes?

**Update:**
I read here [Why does 'git status' ignore the .gitattributes clean filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807979/why-does-git-status-ignore-the-gitattributes-clean-filter) that it isn't possible to make `git status` show the filtered output. It will only show the correct staged files after `git add`. But feel free to prove this wrong.

Comment: what if you commit them to git expanded? AFAIR "Id" should change only if something else changed in file. Would cause slight noise but not fatal.

Comment: change file -> check in with git -> check in with cvs -> keyword expansion -> check in with git AGAIN. As git will have more fine-grained commits, it's called first and more often. Almost every file change will yield 2 commits instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Because the mechanism between CVS and GIT are different. If files expanded by cvs update, that means these files are really changes. So there has a new checksum in git. When you use `git status`, git will display the files which have different checksums by comparing with the checksums in stage area for last time.

In order to the two version control tools have no effect for each other, you can place them in different directories.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm just coming from the two-folder approach and want to explore the possibility of using just one. About the checksums: I can pre-process the files before the checksum is generated by applying filters. This works for commits. It doesn't work for status. Maybe there is a way to also hook into the status generation?